# Copy every files of a dir automatically using post build executions in vs19

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xcopy

I want to build my game using the parameter "produce one file" (i guess, my vs is in french) but this does not copy my Content/ folder

I've searched a bit and found the PostBuild execution thingy in the .csproj. So I tried some things and it does work.

Here is what is made

```
xcopy "$(ProjectDir)Content" "$(ProjectDir)bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\publish\Latest\win86\Content" /s /y
```

but this is not automated at all. I have a fixed output "$(ProjectDir)bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\publish\Latest\win86\Content" so if i want to publish to mac and linux, the files wont be copied in the correct location.

So is there an environment variable that carries the output dir of the publish to have respectively:

```
$(ProjectDir)bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\publish\Latest\win86\    for win-x86
$(ProjectDir)bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\publish\Latest\osx64\    for osx-x64
$(ProjectDir)bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\publish\Latest\lin64\    for linux-x64
```

The folders are hand made and are rooted by hand so i just need a variable like 'OutputDir' or something.

So I can use it like this

```
xcopy "$(ProjectDir)Content" "$(OutputDir)Content" /s /y
```

I was unable to find the answer in Microsoft documentation.

I'll be thankful for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's MSDN's [List of common macros for MSBuild commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/common-macros-for-build-commands-and-properties?view=vs-2019) to use in project file definitions.

Inside you will find:

> $(TargetDir)

> The directory of the primary output file for the build
> (defined as drive + path); includes the trailing backslash ''.

Note also that inside the Properties view of your project inside Visual Studio, next to where you can edit the Post Build scripts, you can click a "Macros >>" button to see a list of macros and what values they resolve to.

[image: macros]

Comment: so now i have xcopy "$(ProjectDir)Content" "$(TargetDir)Content" /s /y

Comment: Glad to hear it worked.  If it truly solves the problem, please consider marking your question as Answered, so others searching later will know that it did.  If it only partially solves the problem, you can add more comments here to clarify things, or update your question with more details about what isn't working.

Comment: Thanks, i forgot to do it